# 2 onClick events within a single DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

What i am trying to achieve is pretty simple. I have a div with an expand/collapse icon and a question mark icon. When a user clicks on one of these icons, the corresponding hidden div's should slide down.

This is working when a user clicks on the expand/collapse icons, but not the question mark.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="toggle_head Header">
    <label>
        <img class="expandCollpse" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/expand_alt.png" height="30px;" />
        <img class="hide expandCollpse" src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/collapse_alt.png" height="30px;" />
    </label>
    <label>Expand</label>
    <label class="showHelp">
        <img src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" height="30px;" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="toggle_body">
    <button type="button" class="btn" style="float:right;">Close</button>
    <label>**Info from expand/collapse icon click** - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</label>
</div>
<div class="helpBody">
    <label>**Info from HELP icon click** - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();
$(".helpBody").hide();

$(".toggle_head").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $this.find('img.expandCollpse').toggle();
    });
});

$(".showHelp").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('div.helpBody').slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".btn").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".toggle_body").slideUp();
})
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/x7k9B/4/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm, there are two hidden DIVs - toggle_body and helpBody. Only toggle_body is appearing.. Check the content.

Comment: Your code is correct. It worked for me too.

Comment: No, when a user clicks on toggle_head, toggle_body should show. When a user clicks on showHelp, helpBody should show.

Comment: Take a look at the labels, one says: <label>Info from expand/collapse icon click.... The other says, <label>Info from HELP icon click

Comment: very asymmetrical code. You have two identical elements ( buttons) which are treated in different way. Redesign logic, simplify and it is going to work. Ansver a question, What should react on click, Is it neccesary for a <div class="toggle_head Header"> to catch an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an updated fiddle with the issue fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/x7k9B/5/

the div was eating the clicks on the help icon.

here's the updated code:

```
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();
$(".helpBody").hide();

$(".toggle_head").click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);

    // is the click event's target the showHelp label? 
    if ($(event.target).closest('label').hasClass('showHelp')) {
        $(".helpBody").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $this.find('img.expandCollpse').toggle();
        });
        return;
    }

    // click event occurred somewhere else on the header div- not on showHelp...
    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $this.find('img.expandCollpse').toggle();
    });
});

$(".btn").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".toggle_body").slideUp();
})
```

Comment: Correct! The main problem is that the code jscript  in ". Toggle_head" always opens the information you do not want when the help button is clicked. And this code ends up overlaying the help button. This tip is the way to correct this.

Comment: @jdanyou - updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/x7k9B/6/ Issue im having is that when a question mark icon is clicked, both sections are toggling.

Comment: @jdanyow - thanks. It seems the solution only work when the helpBody div is after the toggle_body div.. Can this be reversed to helpBody is before toggle_body ?

Comment: here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/x7k9B/10/ (the first expander has helpBody then toggleBody.  the second expander has these reversed.  both work with the same js

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<div class="toggle_head Header">
    <label id="toggle_head">
        <img class="expandCollpse" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/expand_alt.png" height="30px;" />
        <img class="hide expandCollpse" src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/collapse_alt.png" height="30px;" />
    </label>
    <label>Expand</label>
    <label class="showHelp">
        <img src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" height="30px;" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="toggle_body">
    <button type="button" class="btn" style="float:right;">Close</button>
    <label>Info from expand/collapse icon click - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</label>
</div>
<div class="helpBody">
    <label>Info from HELP icon click - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</label>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toggle_body").hide();
        $(".collapse").hide();
        $(".helpBody").hide();

        $("#toggle_head").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $this.find('img.expandCollpse').toggle();
            });
        });

        $(".showHelp").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.helpBody').slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $(".btn").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.closest(".toggle_body").slideUp();
        })
    });
</script>
```